# Yii Framework Session Not Saved After Login

Tags: php, yii, session-state

We have the following function in /rpotected/components/UserIdentity.php:

```
public function authenticate()
    {
            $username = $this->username;
            $password = $this->password;

            $user = Users::model()->find('username=? AND password=?', array($username, $password));
            if($user === NULL){
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_UNKNOWN_IDENTITY;

            }else{
                    $this->username = $user->username;
                    sess('SESS_USER_INFO', $user->attributes);
                    //print_r(sess('SESS_USER_INFO'));
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            }

            return !$this->errorCode;
    }
```

Here's a snippet from /protected/models/Users.php:

```
public function login()
{            
        if($this->_identity===null)
        {
                $username = $this->username;
                $password = md5($this->password);
                //echo "Username: ".$username."<br />Password:".$password;
                $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($username, $password);
                $this->_identity->authenticate();

        }
        if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
        {
                $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 60*20; // 30 days
                //print_r($this->_identity);
                Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);

                //echo "Login Successful";
                return true;
        }
        else{
                //echo "Error";
                $this->addError('password','Incorrect username or password.');
                return false;
        }
```

Problem:  Upon login, clicking on My Profiles link prompts for login again.  Thus, it seems that the session is not storing/saving the login credentials and carrying them through the login lifespan.

How should the authenticate function be modified so that the session information is stored and so that the login credentials are carried forward?

Comment: what is `sess('SESS_USER_INFO', $user->attributes);`?

Comment: I'm thinking its intended to save the login user attributes to the session?

Comment: remove it, it could be conflicting with the yii's session handling

Comment: @BenRowe does yii automatically handle sessions?  Or, are there steps to take to activate session handling in one of the config directives?

Comment: assuming your server is correctly setup for handling sessions (write access to tmp, etc), then yii has no problem using the native php session handler. CWebUser acts as a wrapper for the $_SESSION super global.

Comment: if you want to double check that yii is handling the sessions correctly, try `var_dump($_SESSION['__id']);` it should be set, and it's value should be the username if you're successfully logged in.

Comment: Ben: Unfortunately that won't work. Yii adds stuff behind an md5 of some app specific data - the stateKeyPrefix (or something you set manually). The variable will be something like "6fdbfadd33a6b0413aa16d3049bc6969__id"

Comment: So, I've done some reading on CDbHttpSession which appears to save session data in the YiiSession database table.  Is my Users Controller the best place to include logic to call this?

Comment: SidC you don't call the session stuff yourself. You just add a module entry for 'session' to your configuration and you put in 'class' => 'CDbHttpSession'. Yii will use that class for session mgmt instead of the regular one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check "[session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)" value in php.ini

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 2592000
```

Answer (score -2):

You can store login credentials in a variable of CWebUser class through this way **$this->setState(loogedInUser,$user);** using setState function.

This information is stored in cookies, not is session and you can access it using 
**Yii::app()->user->loogedInUser** at any where.